# Using Index in Python to return all values associated with a User Input

Tags: python

I have a question which should have a very basic solution, however I have not been able to find it.

I have the following code that helps me to pull information on certain stocks. However, how can i slice the data so that it will only give me data for a specific stock.

Example being, I filter the data so that I only obtain stock information for 'TSLA'. Any help will be appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.data import DataReader
from datetime import datetime

symbols = ['GOOG','AAPL','F','TSLA']

df = pd.DataFrame()

for symbol in symbols:
    ClosingPrice = DataReader(symbol, 'yahoo', datetime(2015,1,1), datetime(2015,9,1))
    ClosingPrice = ClosingPrice.reset_index()
    ClosingPrice['Symbol'] = symbol
    df = df.append(ClosingPrice)

    print (df)
```

Comment: What do you want? like `symbols[1]`?

Comment: I would like the entire df data frame to be reprinted but only for the stock that a user inputs. So like in the question, if I want to filter data for TSLA, it will display all the associated information from Jan 1, 2015 to Sep 1, 2015, such as (Open, Low, High, and etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can basically:

```
df.loc[df['Symbol'] == 'TSLA']
```

Here is some [useful docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html).

Comment: Thank you very much for this, I also found a solution using stk_list = ['TSLA'] and then using "isin' feature df[df['Symbol'].isin(stk_list)]. More ways of doing it, I appreciate it!